# What does "twice folded" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, adjectives, ambiguity

**A twice folded card.**

Does this mean that when you open it, it has 4 compartments?

Answer (score 3):

I would take this literally, not as an expression. The card was folded twice. Most likely, this folding results in 4 roughly-equal quadrants when you open it. Since you didn't tell me what sort of folding was done to the card, I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 3):

It is ambiguous; the card could have been folded once, unfolded, and then refolded along the same crease.  Or it could have been folded once into (approximately) halves and then a second time, while folded, to make quarters.  Or it could have been folded into thirds.

Without further context or explanation, no option seems more likely than any other.